# android heart rate and blood oxygen sensor samsung

Tags: android, android-sensors

i am currently developing an android application for my academic project. I want to access the Samsung heart rate sensor and Blood oxygen level sensors. I have register to the Samsung developers and requested for Samsung sensor sdk. I don't think I could able to receive it before this week end. because I have to submit my project within this week. if any one could help to access those sensors without those sdk libraries please write answer. if anyone could offer me those sdk files would be great help to me. please help me. thank you.